# Why did I split this pot in PLO8

Tags: omaha

[![The Final hand][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxOSe.png The Final hand where i dont understand how we could split the pot when i have flush and other guy has 2 pairs.

on table is    8h 2h 10h 7h 8s
My cards are   7s Jh Qh Kc
His cards are  3s 3d Ah 2c
He souldnt have naything better than my flsuh? How can the pot split?

Answer (score 3):

PLO8 is a split pot game, where half the pot is awarded to the player with the best Hi hand, and half the pot is awarded to the player with the best Lo hand.  A hand qualifies to be a Lo hand if it is unpaired and contains no card higher than 8.

Hero in the above hand wins the Hi with the flush, but Villain wins the Lo playing A3 from his hand, making 8732A.

Comment: I had to look up the rules for PLO8 to know why the Ah could not make a flush with the four hearts on the table. Each player must use exactly two cards from their hand, so one heart from the hand is no good.

Comment: @BillOnne Yes, this is true for any Omaha game.